# How can I make an APK stop checking for updates? It's not downloaded from Google play

Tags: application-autoupdate

There's this music app (Fildo 4.2.9) that for a certain reason I don't want to use the latest version of, is there a possible way i can stop it from checking for updates? i literally can't use it because it displays a box that won't go unless it's updated.

Comment: There are only two way: 1. don't allow the app to connect to the server it uses for checking if there are updates. 2. Modify the APK so that it does not check for updates. For both ways there no "one-click" solution.

Comment: Care to explain more on how i can do these stuff? Or how to locate the server or the file that checks for updates?

Comment: Both ways can get pretty complex. The easier way is usually blocking the server. Use one of the packet capture apps or PCapremote to capture the app network traffic (after clearing it's app data). Also make sure that you don't use private DNS feature of Android. Then you should see the server name. Once you got the server name you can try to block it e.g. using Blokada app.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it out.